# I get an "Outdated Client" message when I try to play with my friends

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to go to my friends world, a message comes up and says "could not connect outdated client", and when I try to invite my friends over to my world it won't let them come to my world.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You provided NO details on any errors or anything. No one cann solve your problem if ye don't describe it fully

Comment: Have you tried updating your Minecraft? Check what version you are using, and what version they are using.

Comment: @Ben You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

This message refers to a mismatch between the Client version, and the Host version Minecraft. If you are running two different versions of the game, they will not be able to connect.

In the launcher, you can [choose which version](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_launcher) of Minecraft you wish to play. Make sure you and your friends are choosing the same version, and you will be able to play together.